# Set the size of the inner area of window

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple function that generates JFrame containing an image:

```
 //The window
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 //Topmost component of the window
 Container main = frame.getContentPane();
 //Turns out this is probably the simplest way to render image on screen 
 //with guaranteed 1:1 aspect ratio
 JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
 };
 //Put the image drawer in the topmost window component
 main.add(panel);
 //Set window size to the image size plus some padding dimensions
 frame.setSize(image.getWidth(null)+1, image.getHeight(null)+15);

 frame.setVisible(true);
```

Result:

[image: image description]

I think this happens because the window dimensions include the size of the top bar and the window borders.

I also tried to set the size for `JPanel` and call `pack()` on JFrame:

```
 //Set the size to the panel and let JFrame size itself properly
 panel.setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
 frame.pack();
```

Result is even worse:

[image: image description]

So how can I precisely specify the inner window dimensions in pixels?

[image: image description]

[Here's the full function code.](http://pastebin.com/sw7fCwsW)

Comment: Well you can try inserting image in a JLabel, that may not cause this problem.

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal I started with that. I am not sure why I am not using that solution anymore, but there was a reason I guess.

Comment: The easiest way to display an image it to use a JLabel. Only do custom painting if you are manipulating the image.

Comment: @camickr As I said just before, there was probably some problem with it, because that's what I did first.

Comment: The problem is with your code, not the approach. If you have a special requirement that is not mentioned in the question then state the requirement, otherwise why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the preferred size of the panel by overriding the `getPreferredSize` method of `JPanel` and calling `pack()` on the `JFrame` before making it visible

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }
};
```

See the answers in [Use of overriding getPreferredSize() instead of using setPreferredSize() for fixed size Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866762/use-of-overriding-getpreferredsize-instead-of-using-setpreferredsize-for-fix) on the use and effect of either this technique, or the `setPreferredSize` method

Comment: Awesome! It works and is simpler than I hoped for :)

Comment: @TomášZato, Even simpler is to use a JLabel, since it does this for you.