# Try to use Swing Graphics2d to draw on a panel over a panel, didn't work

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm trying to draw 2 triangles with Graphics 2d. When running the first segment, it's totally correct. But if I run the second segment that I add a panel below the "Graph", the triangles disappear. Could anybody help me with the issue?

Here's the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class Draw_A_Triangle extends JPanel {
    public Draw_A_Triangle() {}
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    work(g2d, Color.RED,30,45,60,90,60,90);
    work(g2d, Color.blue,15,22.5,30,45,30,45);

    }
    // set a method to draw the 2 triangles
    public void work(Graphics2D g2d, Color c, double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3) {

        Path2D.Double p = new Path2D.Double();
        g2d.setColor(c);
        p.moveTo(x1, y1);
        p.lineTo(x2, y2);
        p.lineTo(x3, y3);
        g2d.fill(p);
        g2d.draw(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //set the JFrame
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Triangle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);

//        //segment 1
//        Draw_A_Triangle panel = new Draw_A_Triangle();
//        frame.add(panel);
//        frame.setVisible(true);

//        segment 2
        Draw_A_Triangle panel = new Draw_A_Triangle();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(panel);
        frame.add(p);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: You have added a *superb* example of a [mre]. 

Comment: As to *why* the first panel disappears, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe/13881481#13881481). But the core of the solution is that **one** panel should have access to a list of all shapes to paint, then iterate the list in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend the following changes.

- don't set the size of the frame.  Set the size of the JPanel to eliminate the frame border from taking up panel space. This is overriding the method in the `JPanel` instance.

```
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,500);
    }
```

Then do the following:

- `frame.pack()` - size the frame based on layout requirements and size preferences of its components.
- `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` - centers frame on screen.
- You're already subclassing `JPanel` so no need to create a new one.  Just add `panel` to `frame`.
- And the first thing in overidding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` should be
   `super.paintComponent(g);` Otherwise, required functionality like setting the background color of the panel won't work.
- and if you want to set the background of the panel, use `panel.setBackground(<someColor>)`

```
Draw_A_Triangle panel = new Draw_A_Triangle();
 panel.setBackground(Color.white);
 frame.add(panel);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

I recommend you check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more on painting.  Go to `Really Big Index` and search the TOC for `painting`

Comment: I would `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);` rather than `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` for most windows. A splash screen (for counter-example) should be centered on-screen. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks, it works! I added it to the project perfectly.

Comment: Yes.  But then other classes/methods can change it.  This is to prevent that and the recommended way of doing it.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866762/use-of-overriding-getpreferredsize-instead-of-using-setpreferredsize-for-fix) may prove interesting.  But ultimately it's up to the programmer.

Comment: In the past I have wanted to subclass String.  But it's final so I can't.  Them's the breaks.